# How to convert IMU data to quaternion orientation

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-kinetic, quaternion, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to fuse my IMU data (and GPS data) with the package robot_localization.
Therefore, I have to put my IMU data into a sensor_msgs/Imu message.
I know it is possible to convert my IMU data (accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer) into a quaternion orientation message. However, I wonder if there is a package available to do this transformation for me, or do I have to write code myself? If so, how would I start?

Thanks in advance!
Kind regards Robbe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286016/how-to-convert-imu-data-to-quaternion-orientation/) by [Robbe_C](https://answers.ros.org/users/34238/robbe_c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to clarify - you are not converting your accelerometer / gyros / magnetometer measurements into an orientation, you are using those raw measurements to estimate your orientation. The [madgwick](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick) and [complementary](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_complementary_filter) filter are both capable of doing exactly what you need.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-20**:
The robot_localization package that the OP originally suggested can also do this.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-03-20**:
@ahendrix I didn't think robot_localization dealt directly with magnetometer measurements. Can you explain how you would do this?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-21**:
I believe the navsat_transform_node can handle magnetometer measurements: http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/navsat_transform_node.html

**Comment by [Robbe_C](https://answers.ros.org/users/34238/robbe_c/) on 2018-03-21**:
Thank you for the quick respone!
I think you are talking about the use_odometry_yaw parameter of navsat_transform_node, right?
Maybe that's even easier.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-03-21**:
I don't think the navsat_transform_node is what you need. Navsat_transform is used to transform GPS measurements into odometry which you can fuse in robot_localization.